How can I send custom http requests on behalf of any app. Like sending requests to api of any server like google, etc. through random app?
I was wondering if there is any way I can send custom requests to api, servers through any random applications on Windows. Like there are mods of games which sends applications to game's api but through game. Hope you got me!
I haven't got any way of doing it

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take the tour, and read how to ask. This will also be of use to you: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/
